# Setting Application.ErrorCheckingOptions.BackgroundChecking with Spreadsheetgear

Tags: spreadsheetgear

What's the equivalent of doing `Application.ErrorCheckingOptions.BackgroundChecking = False` with Spreadsheetgear ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SpreadsheetGear does not provide formula error-checking options like this, so there are no equivalent options in SpreadsheetGear's API.

As I understand it, BackgroundChecking is a setting specific to the Excel Application itself and nothing that could be set in the XLS or XLSX/XLSM file format itself.  So even if we did support such a feature, I don't think it would persist within the workbook file and upon opening in Excel later on, if that is what you are trying to do.